# Возможно ли обновить поле в ряду, полученному через mysqli_fetch_assoc, без какого-либо ID?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Php-скрипт обрабатывает поочередно все ряды выборки через функцию `mysqli_fetch_assoc`. Если выполняются определённые условия - значение в ряду необходимо обновить. С этой задачей у меня не возникает проблем, когда есть столбец типа ID:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
if ($row["data"]==$condition)
  mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE `$table` SET `data` = '$newdata' WHERE `$table`.`ID` = '".$row["ID"]."';");
}
```

Но если таблица состоит всего из одного столбца 'data', без столбца 'ID'? Возможно ли php-скрипту обновить значение именно тому ряду, который был получен через функцию `mysqli_fetch_assoc`?

Если нет, то подскажите, пожалуйста, другой способ как можно было бы осуществить подобное обновление данных в таблице из одного столбца (чтобы сохранить php-скрипту цикл, в котором c каждым рядом проходит проверка условия).

Comment: Если объем небольшой - берете данные, делаете с ними что хотите в скрипте, фильтруете... А дальше делаете `drop table`, `create table`, `insert into` ......без дропа `truncate tablel` -> `insert into`........ потому что апдейт надо делать по какому-то условию делать.....если поля `data` не уникальные то и привязаться не к чему..... да и в принципе таблица с одним полем - бессмысленна сама как таковая

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Да понимаю, что таблица с одним полем бессмысленна, просто скрипт будет работать с таблицами, в которых структура может отличаться, и идентификационное поле может называться по-разному. При этом, могут обрабатываться таблицы большого объёма (конкретный пример: таблица wp_posts из базы wordpress с несколькими сотнями записей), функция `mysqli_fetch_assoc` - показывает неплохие результаты быстродействия и всем удовлетворяет до того момента, пока известна структура обрабатываемой базы данных.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Если таблица у меня общим объёмом 10MB - указанный вами метод приемлим? И если 100MB (это уже гипотетически)? Для работы с массивом такого объёма потребуется ли дополнительная память PHP, или интерпретатору потребуется ровно столько оперативной памяти, сколько занимает таблица?

Comment: Ну на работчей базе пересоздавать таблицы нельзя. В них могут быть поля типа автоинкремент в которые вы уже не вставите старые данные, а на них могут быть ссылки. Так что скрипт должен через таблицы описания схемы получать информацию о первичном ключе и давать update на основе него. Вариант 2: select * и создание `update set все-колонки where все-колонки=старым-значениям`

Comment: @Mike Да, то что надо, даже не подумал о таком варианте. Благодарю.

Comment: @Mike про `update все-колонки where` что-то не вспомнил, а по поводу ключей......ведь автор же написал, что таблица из одной колонки состоит, без всяких айдишников и инкрементов, соответственно ни с чем особо и не свяжешь её в таком виде

Comment: @Mike Сейчас протестировал ваш метод: всё проходит отлично с тестовыми записями небольшого содержания, но вот с реальными записями (содержащими html-код, с кавычкам и прочими символами, по несколько килобайт) - обновление не проходит. Функцию вызываю используя такой запрос: `mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE `table` SET `data` = '$newdata' WHERE `table`.`data` = '$originaldata';");` - видимо из-за спецсимволов в данных - запрос не проходит. Я весьма поверхностно знаком с mySQL. Не подскажите, как решить эту проблему? Может есть какая функция конвертирующая строку в удобоваримый для SQL вид?

Comment: не стоит значения пихать в текст запроса. Лучше поставить кучу '?' вместо всех подставляемых значений и привязывать значения к ним http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: @Mike Сейчас попробовал вот так, по этому мануалу: `$stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, "UPDATE `table` SET `data` = ? WHERE `table`.`data` = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $newcontent, $originalcontent);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);`    - в результате такое же поведение, как и прежде - маленькие тестовые записи обновились, а реальные с HTML-кодом остаются без изменений. В чём здесь может быть ошибка? Или может быть есть ещё какой-то более подходящий способ для больших строк?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В комментариях Mike подсказал оптимальный вариант для решения этой задачи:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
if ($row["data"]==$condition) {
  $stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, "UPDATE `".$table."` SET `data` = ? WHERE `".$table."`.`data`=?");
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $newdata, $originaldata);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
```

Если в данных присутствуют русские символы и они в UTF-8, то перед этим еще необходимо прописать:

```
mysqli_set_charset($connection,'utf8');
```